# Spring batch integration file lock access

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I have a spring batch integration where multiple servers are polling a single file directory.  This causes a problem where a file can be processed up by more than one.  I have attempted to add a `nio-lock` onto the file once a server has got it but this locks the file for processing so it can't read the contents of the file.

Is there a spring batch/integration solution to this problem or is there a way to rename the file as soon as it is picked up by a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to use `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` with the shared `MetadataStore`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metadata-store

So, only one instance of your application will be able to pick up a file.

Even if we find a solution for `nio-lock`, you should understand that lock means "do not touch until freed". Therefore when one instance has done its work, another one is ready to pick up the file. I guess that isn't your goal.

Comment: Thank you Artem I will look into using this.